# Change Image every 20 seconds Javascript with Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I found this code from here but I need to add these things in this javascript.

1. Fade Effect
2. Want to show images with 2 rows, means I will add 10 images. 5 Images will show on 1st row and 5 images will show in 2nd row.
3. Want to add Text for every picture e.g. Name and Price
4. Mouse over image changing stop

```html
<script>
    var links = [
    "abc.org",
    "def.org",
    "ghi.org",
    "ghi33.org"
    ];
    var images = [
    "https://dmcfebaedy6rh.cloudfront.net/product/front/white/spl5596.360x180.1443167798.jpg",
    "https://dmcfebaedy6rh.cloudfront.net/product/front/white/mt6050.360x180.1430798334.jpg",
    "https://dmcfebaedy6rh.cloudfront.net/product/front/white/pl5087.360x180.1423189940.jpg", 
    "https://dmcfebaedy6rh.cloudfront.net/product/front/white/spl5596.360x180.1443167798.jpg"
    ];
    var i = 0;
    var renew = setInterval(function(){
        if(links.length == i){
            i = 0;
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById("bannerImage").src = images[i]; 
        document.getElementById("bannerLink").href = links[i]; 
        i++;

    }
    },10000);
</script>
<a id="bannerLink" href="abc.org" onclick="void window.open(this.href); return false;">
<img id="bannerImage" src="https://d37j5ujucg66b1.cloudfront.net/product/front/white/pl5393.360x180.1456885745.jpg">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with a question like this is, we have no idea what you're really aiming for. What we need from you is a little bit of code so we can see where you're heading.

I'm sure any number of us could throw together a little carousel that works, but that's not really what this site is for. It's to help people learn and work out what they did wrong or what they need to do to solve a problem.

That being said it would feel wrong of me to write all this without presenting some code.

```js
var caraSel = document.querySelector(".simple-image");
var imageSel = document.querySelectorAll(".bannerLink");
var imageSelMax = imageSel.length - 1;
var imageInt = 0;
var imageIntNext = 1;

var renew = setInterval(function() {
  imageSel[imageInt].classList.add("hidden");
  imageSel[imageIntNext].classList.remove("hidden");

  imageSelMax === imageInt ? imageInt = 0 : ++imageInt;
  imageSelMax === imageIntNext ? imageIntNext = 0 : ++imageIntNext;
}, 1000);

caraSel.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  clearInterval(renew);
});

caraSel.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  renew = setInterval(function() {
    imageSel[imageInt].classList.add("hidden");
    imageSel[imageIntNext].classList.remove("hidden");

    imageSelMax === imageInt ? imageInt = 0 : ++imageInt;
    imageSelMax === imageIntNext ? imageIntNext = 0 : ++imageIntNext;
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.simple-image {
  position: relative;
  width: 360px;
  height: 180px;
}
.bannerLink {
  position: fixed;
  background: #FFF;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  will-change: opacity;
  transition: opacity .6s ease-in;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.bannerLink.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="simple-image">
  <a class="bannerLink" href="abc.org" onclick="void window.open(this.href); return false;">
    <img class="bannerImage" src="https://d37j5ujucg66b1.cloudfront.net/product/front/white/pl5393.360x180.1456885745.jpg">#1
  </a>

  <a class="bannerLink hidden" href="def.org" onclick="void window.open(this.href); return false;">
    <img class="bannerImage" src="https://dmcfebaedy6rh.cloudfront.net/product/front/white/mt6050.360x180.1430798334.jpg">#2
  </a>

  <a class="bannerLink hidden" href="ghi.org" onclick="void window.open(this.href); return false;">
    <img class="bannerImage" src="https://dmcfebaedy6rh.cloudfront.net/product/front/white/pl5087.360x180.1423189940.jpg">#3
  </a>

  <a class="bannerLink hidden" href="ghi33.org" onclick="void window.open(this.href); return false;">
    <img class="bannerImage" src="https://dmcfebaedy6rh.cloudfront.net/product/front/white/spl5596.360x180.1443167798.jpg">#4
  </a>
</div>
```

Sped up of course be you get the idea.